# usb to serial not working

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

This is my first time integrating Serial to USB in a C# application, so please pardon me if this sounds like a stupid question.
I have Class IV laser. I am integrating that in to my C# application.
My problem is I can connect to the laser, I can send data to the laser but i don't get any return from the laser.

```
    private void Bt_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
                serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
                serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
                serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                ConenctToLaser("COM3", serialPort);
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            int bytesRead = sp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public void ConenctToLaser(string port, SerialPort serialPort)
    {
        StreamReader openfile = new StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\commands.txt");
        if (serialPort.IsOpen == false)
        {
            serialPort.Open();
            string command = "";
            command = openfile.ReadLine();
            while(command!=null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
                serialPort.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                command = openfile.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

The commands.txt includes my commands. which are 
\r
MTT\r
MCM\r
SPR300\r
on different lines
When i send these commands to the laser all i get back is the echo. So in reality when i send ("MTT\r") i should get back the temperature of the hardware. When i test my hardware in putty it works i get return for all the commands above. Here's the definition for one of the commands from the .pdf they have provided.
**Laser Temperature Command: MTT\r
Description: The laser actual laser temperature expressed in XX.X degC**

After hours of researching I found the answer to my question. From what i read online it seems like the SerialPort class by Microsoft doesn't work very well with all the serial Hardware. So I would need to use a wrapper class to work with Win32 API.
I found this article which explains how to use Win32 class to communicate with  the serial device. It also has a wrapper to call the Win32 methods. You can read  all about it and download all the code from the below link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301786.aspx

Hope this helps somebody who's having the same problem.

Comment: Don't send the prompt.  Just use `serialPort.WriteLine(command);`

Comment: In case you need it. Here's the link to .PDF of the laser hardware manual. Read from page 31.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2012sgjbkfvkz8u/PD-LD%20172-12885-F%20LUXXMASTER%20MINI%20RAMAN%20BOXX%20OPERATING%20MANUAL%20REV.PDF?dl=0

Comment: Already tried removing the prompt. No luck

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Did you type `\r` into the file, or did you put in a carriage-return?  Neither reading from a text-file, nor sending to a serial port, will cause replacement of escape sequences.  That only happens, during compilation, for string literals in source code.

Comment: @BenVoigt I type \r in to the file. I thought \r is the carriage return is that correct ? Can you also give me an example on how else would i write my string as. I already tried writeline() method. That gives me the same behavior.